# If my ASP.NET webapp isn't fit for runtime?

Tags: asp.net, validation, runtime, environment

I want to run some tests when my ASP.NET webapp comes online (preferably before anyone tries to access it), to make sure all of my runtime dependencies are available as I expect them to be.

When is a good time to perform these tests (e.g. Application_Start, Application_Init, somewhere else, etc), and what's a good technique for making my webapp unavailable to users if my tests fail (it shares an app pool with other apps I don't want to affect)?

Comment: What version of IIS, or does this need to be IIS version nuetral?

Comment: Nuetral is always good, but 6 would be a start.

Comment: Do you have (or have the resources for) test, staging, and live environments? (or at lead a test and live environment) so that you can test deployment issues before they get to the server? I know you can get at what you're asking as well, but it would be a good practice to have these environments if you're able.

Comment: @David Stratton: Their configurations differ intermittently with schedules/reasons I don't control. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to put your checks in the Application_Start event, and update a static property (or properties) in the Global class with the result of your test.

If you're using master pages, each master page (I've personally never seen more than 2 base master classes in a project) could check the static property in the Global class, and redirect to an "app offline" page if appropriate. Since the static property would only be updated when the application started, there shouldn't be any performance impact.

The code in your master page's OnLoad event might look like this...

```
if (!Global.WasDependencyCheckSuccessful)
{
//redirect to error page
}
```

If you're not using master pages, this may not be the best solution (because you would need to update each web form in your site individually).

Comment: My runtime tests capture to the operations log system details about the failures, but they also capture user-appropriate language about why the application isn't yet fit for use.  I integrated your solution into our BasePage (we try to keep master pages reserved for more cosmetic concerns).  I write to the Response instead of redirecting, so that the "denied" screen can include non-sensitive details about why the application isn't yet ready for use.  I initially preferred the app_offline.htm solution, but this has worked splendidly.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in the Application_Start event in the global.asax.

To bring your app offline, simply create an [App_Offline.htm file](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/04/aspnet-20-features-appofflinehtm.html).  I do it on our server by having an "App_Offline.html" file and when I need to bring it offline, I have the code rename it to change the extension from .html to .htm, and reverse that to bring it back online.

Of course, to bring it back online, you have to do it from code outside of your website, or do it manually, because if the file is there, the code in your website won't run...

Comment: +1. I like this approach because you use the built-in functionality but I think the manual aspect of this makes it less desirable

Comment: I agree, but (if I'm guessing his motives correctly) it sounds like if the test fails, there's probably work to be done (maybe edit code, alter a DB, set permissions, etc), so he'll need to control when it becomes available again anyway, so this might be the right approach anyway.

Comment: I love this solution, but we can't accommodate the permissions required to create that file at runtime.